what problem do I have with this SQL statement? PHP and SQL
Trying to understand PHP and SQL right now and I'm getting this error here, being honest I don't really get what is trying to tell me or what I should do, have been looking for a good while trying to solve the issue but I don't really know what to do, would appreciate a hand from somebody with a keen eye for this
EDIT: Trying to use this code to change values in "clients" table, editting them, so that's why I'm using id to look in the table for a row that matches $id, but I don't really know if I'm doing it correctly with this

(Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[id]' at line 1 in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEG\editcliente.php:30 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\TEG\editcliente.php(30): mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM c...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\TEG\editcliente.php on line 30)
all with this code of right here
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$database = "totalmk_db";

$connection = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $database);

$id = "";
$name = "";
$lastname = "";
$idnumber = "";
$email = "";
$phone = "";

$errorMessage = "";
$successMessage = "";

if ( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'GET') {

    if ( !isset($_GET["id"]) ) {
        header("location: clientes.php");
        exit;
    }

    $id = $_GET["id"];

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE id=$id";
    $result = $connection->query($sql);
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

    if (!$row) {
        header("location: clientes.php");
        exit;
    }

    $name = $row["name"];
    $lastname = $row["lastname"];
    $idnumber = $row["idnumber"];
    $email = $row["email"];
    $phone = $row["phone"];

} else {

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $lastname = $_POST["lastname"];
    $idnumber = $_POST["idnumber"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $phone = $_POST["phone"];

    do {
        if ( empty($name) || empty($lastname) || empty($idnumber) || empty($email) || empty($phone) ) {
            $errorMessage = "Se requiere que llene todos los campos";
            break;
        }

        $sql = "UPDATE clients" .
                "SET name = '$name', lastname = '$lastname', idnumber = '$idnumber', email = '$email', phone = '$phone' " . 
                "WHERE id = $id";

        $result = $connection->query($sql);

        if (!$result) {
            $errorMessage = "Invalid query: " . $connection->error;
            break;
        }

        $successMessage = "Cliente editado correctamente!";

    } while (false);
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Añadir cliente</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/clientes.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="lista-clientes">
            <h2>Añadir Cliente</h2>

            <?php 
            if ( !empty($errorMessage) ) {
                echo "
                <div>
                    <p class='error'>$errorMessage</p>
                </div>
                ";
            }
            ?>

            <form method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                    <label>Nombre</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="<?php echo $name; ?>">
                    
                    <label>Apellido</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" value="<?php echo $lastname; ?>">

                    <label>Cédula</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="idnumber" value="<?php echo $idnumber; ?>">

                    <label>Email</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>">

                    <label>Número de Teléfono</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>">

                <?php
                
                if ( !empty($successMessage) ) {
                    echo "
                    <div class='alert' role='alert'>
                        <p class='success'>$successMessage</p>
                    </div>
                    ";
                }
                ?>

                <div class="">
                    <button type="submit" class="submit">Aceptar</button>
                    <a class="cancel" href="clientes.php">Volver</a>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>


You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, take advantage of prepared statements and bind_param. This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur.  But since you're creating the sql manually for right now, echo out your query to see what it looks like.

What is $_GET["id"]? Did you print the query?

got that from a vid so I don't really know what's going on with it, what I'm trying to do with the id is using it to edit values in my "clients" table, in the db, lemme explain that in my post too, whoops

Whatever video you watched is showing you insecure, obsolete and verbose techniques for building your queries and handling SQL errors. Either the video is 20 years old, or it was made by someone whose knowledge is 20 years out of date.

Let's hope you don't get an Irish name like O'Brian.
